# Centrality for graphs with negative weights?

Tags: graph-theory

We can calculate eigenvector centrality for graphs with non-negative weights for the edges. Is there any version of it which can be used for graphs with negative weights?

Comment: For all those not familiar with this concept :(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvector_centrality)